# ArchLinux on a virtual Hard Drive - Will creating a desktop install on my real computer or the virtual one?

Tags: linux, powershell, arch-linux, qemu

I have this command for powershell on windows to run arch Linux in QEMU:

```
.\qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -cdrom E:\archlinux.iso -m 3G -hda linuxMint.img -drive format=raw,file=E:\Data
```

It loads up fine but I want to create my own desktop so I need to install ArchLinux but if I install it would it install on my real computer or would it install it to the Data.VHD file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running in the virtual linux, and making changes to the virtual linux, they should only affect the virtual linux and not your host ("real") computer.

If you're at all confused about where you might be installing an operating system, you should have a good backup copy of any data on the computer just in case (should always have a good backup anyway really).

Comment: @Dextron, It will install where you install it.  Are you asking where you should install it, whether there would be a problem if you install it on one or the other, or something else?